# How to read cookies in Scala play?

Tags: security, scala, playframework

I'm adding Cookie like so:

```
              Redirect(routes.UserPage.form(usersignin.email)).withCookies(Cookie("guid", md5hash1cookie))
```

How could i read it?

If i use:

```
println(Http.Request.current().cookies.get("guid"));
```

and i get error:

not found: value Http

UPD 1:

```
Correct way to use is 
  def form(msg: String = "") = Action {
    request => {
      //  guid = guId.toString();
        println(request.cookies.get("guid"));
...

  }
}
```

How to get value out of coockie? println(request.cookies.get("guid")); returns Some(Cookie(guid,7a3bdea2ba59a196c02fb7bdbcdb4e26,None,/,None,false,false))

and i need just 7a3bdea2ba59a196c02fb7bdbcdb4e26 returned as string.

Solution:

```
for(gu <- request.cookies.get("guid")){
          println(gu.value);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a shared state containing the requests in the Scala Play APIs, instead you will have to use the `Action { request =>` way to define actions, on the request you can then access the cookies through `request.cookies`

Comment: Thanks, please check upd 1 section in question

Comment: cookies.get("key") returns an Option[String] since it may not be defined, Option is from the scala standard library so you could read up on how to work with it here for example: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option